# I have some theorical questions about this exercise in Ruby: "Convert numbers into letters"

Tags: ruby

Hi everyone I'm a *newbie* and last week I've started this Ruby tutorial: https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/, but when I've arrived to the ***'Writing your own methods'*** chapter 8 (https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_08.html) I have encountered some difficulties. I've read all the chapter and I did some of the exercises, here is one:

"I think another example method would be helpful here. We'll call this one englishNumber. It will take a number, like 22, and return the english version of it (in this case, the string 'twenty-two'). For now, let's have it only work on integers from 0 to 100.

Expand upon englishNumber. First, put in thousands. So it should return 'one thousand' instead of 'ten hundred' and 'ten thousand' instead of 'one hundred hundred'.

Expand upon englishNumber some more. Now put in millions, so you get 'one million' instead of 'one thousand thousand'. Then try adding billions and trillions. How high can you go?"

**The code** I expanded:

```
def englishNumber number
  if number < 0
    return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
  end
  if number == 0
    return 'zero'
  end
  numString = ''

  onesPlace = ['one',     'two',       'three',    'four',     'five', 'six',     'seven',     'eight',    'nine']
  tensPlace = ['ten',     'twenty',    'thirty',   'forty',    'fifty', 'sixty',   'seventy',   'eighty',   'ninety']
  teenagers = ['eleven',  'twelve',    'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']

#trillion
  left  = number
  write = left/1000000000000
  left = left - write*1000000000000

  if write > 0
    trillions = englishNumber write
    numString = numString + trillions + ' trillion'
    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' '
    end
  end

#billion
  write = left/1000000000
  left = left - write*1000000000

  if write > 0
    billions = englishNumber write
    numString = numString + billions + ' billion'
    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' '
    end
  end

#million
  write = left/1000000
  left = left - write*1000000

  if write > 0
    millions = englishNumber write
    numString = numString + millions + ' million'
    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' '
    end
  end

#thousand
  write = left/1000
  left  = left - write*1000

  if write > 0
    thousands = englishNumber write
    numString = numString + thousands + ' thousand'
    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' '
    end
  end

#hundred
  write = left/100
  left  = left - write*100

  if write > 0
    hundreds  = englishNumber write
    numString = numString + hundreds + ' hundred'
    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' '
  end
end

#tens
  write = left/10
  left  = left - write*10

  if write > 0
    if ((write == 1) and (left > 0))
      numString = numString + teenagers[left-1]
      left = 0
    else
      numString = numString + tensPlace[write-1]
    end

    if left > 0
      numString = numString + '-'
    end
  end

#ones
  write = left
  left  = 0

  if write > 0
    numString = numString + onesPlace[write-1]
  end
  return number.to_s + '=' + numString #double equal sign between number and numString, why?
end

#test
puts englishNumber(  0)
puts englishNumber(  9)
puts englishNumber( 10)
puts englishNumber( 11)
puts englishNumber( 17)
puts englishNumber( 32)
puts englishNumber( 88)
puts englishNumber( 99)
puts englishNumber(100)
puts englishNumber(101)
puts englishNumber(234)
puts englishNumber(10000)
puts englishNumber(1000000)
puts englishNumber(1000000000000)

gets.chomp
```

**I did everything right, so it's more a problem about aesthetics. But I have also some theorical questions on some things I didn't understand:**

1. Why does the *equal sign* appear 2 times in the output? Why is there a number between them?
2. In the last line of the method, just above `end` I also tried to write `puts number.to_s + '=' + numString` instead of `return number.to_s + '=' + numString` and with bigger numbers it give me this error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`, why?
3. In the original code, the author only writes`numString` at the end, how does it work? Why did the metod return the local variable without writing `puts` before? And what is the difference between `return` and `puts`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See [How to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should limit the question to ...one question and post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think without all the code, It can't be understood. Is it alright if it's this long?

Comment: Hi Ludovico.  What Viktor is saying is that you have three problems, in SO normally you write one post per problem.  Having said that otherwise, you've given a solid background and at this stage in your journey don't fret too much about the minimally reproducible thing.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the advice, next time I'll do a shorter post for each problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because this algorithm is recursive. The method calls itself in several places. For example, when the input is `234` it calls `hundreds  = englishNumber 2` and writes the result `2=two hundred` to `numString` variables, then it infers `thirty-four` from `34` and put everything together `234=2=two hundred thirty-four`.
2. `puts` is a method that prints a string and returns `nil`. `return` is a keyword that returns a specific result.
3. Every block of code in Ruby returns the last evaluated statement. At the end of the block, it is unnecessary to explicitly call `return`.

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark this answer as correct if it is. Thank you.

Comment: Last thing, how do I write the code in a way that outputs, 234 = two hundred thirty-four?

Comment: Change the last line from `return number.to_s + '=' + numString` to `numString`. Add the equal sing outside of the method `result =  englishNumber(234); puts "234=#{result}"`